# Problem with Terminal while creating a bootable USB stick on OS X

Tags: live-usb, usb-drive, macosx

I'm following the instructions to create a bootable USB stick on OS X and everything is fine until step number 8: I have executed sudo, entered my password and now nothing is happening.

I tried to go to step number 9 and ejected the USB stick and nothing happened. So I took it out manually and then the terminal reacted saying that it could not find the device.
I tried to see if my USB stick worked on my ASUS EEE PC (where I want to install Ubuntu) and of course it didn't.

So I started the whole procedure again and don't know what I should do after entering my password - I am not getting any error message.

Comment: Try [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) as it deals with Macs and general writes to USB sticks.

Answer (score 1):

It always helps if you specify the site, which describes the steps you are following ;)
In case you are following [these instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) - the command is not just `sudo`, but

```
  sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m
```

where you need to replace the path accordingly. You can try this one, which seems much better formatted:

[How to install Ubuntu on MacBook using USB Stick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this on a mac, and it **takes a very long time** - I think around 3-5 minutes.

Does it just start a new prompt like:

```
Maco@macosx ~$: sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m
Maco@macosx ~$:█
```

If so, then something's definetley wrong. Or does it start a new line with a flashing cursor, like this:

```
Maco@macosx ~$: sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m
█
```

If so, it means it is copying the image and you probrably should leave it alone for some time (Especially (if your USB has a light indicator) if the light indicator on your flash drive is flashing - this means it is being accessed.), as I said, maybe 3-5 minutes, maybe longer.

And make sure that you are executing the **command as a whole**, not just sudo (As Stefan Buynov answered), so the location is probrably something like:

```
sudo dd if=~/Downloads/Ubuntu-12-04-i386.iso of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m
```

Comment: You might want to click the '✔' tick symbol next to my answer - thanks!